# iptables forward from host to guest interferes with vm-vm communication

Tags: iptables, kvm

My iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             nginx                tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             nginx                tcp dpt:https

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Also:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

I have several VMs in 192.168.122.0/24, one is the nginx receiving 80 and 443.  All networking works properly except when VMs request :80 and :443 from each other, even when doing so from a FQDN (which should land on the nginx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this qualifies as an "answer" but it did solve my problem.  By editing my /etc/hosts and overriding the public-IP with the internal VM IP, everything starts to work properly.  I'm guessing that its the round-trip through the public IP that breaks, but I am not entirely sure.